# Find out how long a MacBook has been running since its production

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, time

Is it possible to find out how long a MacBook has been turned on since its production?

Comment: if it's got the original battery, I suppose the cycle count might give an indication? Apple Menu >>> About This Mac >>> System Report >>> Power >>> Health Info

Answer (score 4):

There's a Terminal command `ac`

> ```
> AC(8)                     BSD System Manager's Manual                  AC(8)
>
> NAME
>      ac -- display connect-time accounting
>
> SYNOPSIS
>      ac [-d] [-p] [-w file] [users ...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>      A record of individual login and logout times are written to the system
>      log by login(8) and launchd(8), respectively.  The program ac examines
>      these records and writes the accumulated connect time (in decimal hours)
>      for all logins to the standard output.
>
>      Options available:
>
>      -d      Display the connect times in 24 hour chunks.
>
>      -p      Display individual user totals.
>
>      -w file
>              Read raw connect time data from file, instead of the system log. >
>      users ...
>              Display totals for the given individuals only.
>
>      If no arguments are given, ac displays the total amount of login time for
>      all active accounts on the system.
> ```

It looks about right when I type it in my new machine, but my 9-year-old Mac Pro gives the same figure for its current user as total hours - which means it's lost track of my old account [still active on there but rarely used now] which as been in place since 2008. It just gives 0 hours.

It wouldn't be able to account for any hours the machine may have been on with no-one logged in.